# How can I find the mobile phone manufacturer using javascript on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-browser

When the user visits my html page using the mobile browser, I want to know the device type and manufacturer. Is it possible?

If you open the web site [www.mhltech.org/DoIHaveMHL.aspx](http://www.mhltech.org/DoIHaveMHL.aspx) from a mobile browser, it will identify the mobile device (like Motorola Moto G 2nd Gen 2014, Asus Google Nexus 7, etc.). It is what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you do any research? E.g. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/mobile-phone-detection-brand-model-browser-etc

Comment: I have done some search on the internet. Most of the solutions talk about identifying the mobile browser (through user agent). I was looking for specific brand and model. I missed the discussion mentioned by @jonrsharpe . It  mentions some of the third party solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js).

You can use `platform.manufacturer;` to solve your problem.

Comment: I was looking for a way to find the device brand and model, not a third part solution. I have went through the platform.js, could make out the logic they were using.

Answer (score 2):

In my case ua-parser-js was the best free solution.
The minified version is on https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/tree/master/dist

What you need to do then is like

```
<script src="ua-parser.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var parser = new UAParser();
var result = parser.getResult();
alert(result.device.vendor);

</script>
```

I have tried platform.js and mobile-detect.js before this one, but their detection range was too narrow for my application, as my own phone was an "Unknown Phone" for them.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

> You can use `window.navigator.userAgent`,

It will tell you the Device and browser information like

*[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Samsung SM-G900H Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecho) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari537.36]*

and you just need to extract the bracket value which you need, and you got the device info.

To explore visit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/exploring-javascript-device-apis

Comment: I am aware of userAgent. I was looking for a method to get the exact information about the brand and model of the device.

Comment: userAgent gives you all the information related with Browser/Device,

for device info, Extract the first bracket information that contains the device [Brand, Model, OS, ...]