# How to detect huawei devices that use anroid operating system with JS

Tags: javascript

I want mobile users to direct to stores. My code below work well on android and ios devices but huawei devices acting like android because of their android os. I wonder if there is a way  detect huawei devices that use anroid operating system from browser.

NOTE: userAgent detect operation system, not detect huawei devices that use anroid operating system

```
   <script>

        
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
// Huawei Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"

if (userAgent.includes("HUAWEI") || userAgent.includes("huawei") || userAgent.includes("Huawei")) {
    window.location.replace("https://appgallery.huawei.com/app/C104724711");

} else if (userAgent.includes("Android")) {
    window.location.replace("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emlakbank.mobil&hl=tr&gl=US");
} else if (userAgent.includes("iPhone") || userAgent.includes("Ipad") || userAgent.includes("iPod")) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/emlak-kat%C4%B1l%C4%B1m/id1467874818?l=tr";
    }, 25);
    window.location("https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/emlak-kat%C4%B1l%C4%B1m/id1467874818?l=tr");
    //If the second line of code gives a result then the first row is never executed.
} else {
    //cant be sure about device, so redirect to home page
    //  window.location.replace("https://google.ro");
}
            </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921754/if-the-device-is-huawei

Comment: Well what does the Huawei user agent actually look like? How does the code you have fail to detect it?

Comment: NOTE: userAgent detect operation system, not detect huawei devices that use anroid operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get the Device maker's name from the user agent. You can check http://whatsmyuseragent.org/ whatever the information is available only that information you will get it. If you are looking for more details information that can only be possible with mobile applications